# Find group elements α and β in S5 such that |α|=3, |β|=3 and |αβ|=5

Tags: abstract-algebra

My attempt:
Since |αβ|=5, so the chain length of α must be 1 or 5 and β must be 5 or 1 respectively (as |αβ|=lcm(length of α, length of β) . But, in such a case, no α,β is possible with order 3. I am not sure whether I am thinking on the right line.

Please help me out.

Comment: The fact on the order of $\alpha\beta$ holds if and only if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have disjoint support. This is where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(123)(345)=(12345)$

Body must be at least 30 characters so add this line.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just one more thing, is there a way to generalize such question or we have to tackle such question independently.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: can you decompose the cycle $(1,2,3,4,5)$ into two cycles of length $3$ (which intersect in one point)?

Comment: Thank you, can we also generalize this method for such questions?

Comment: @Utkarsh let $3\leq k\leq n$ and let $a$ be a cycle of $k$ in $S_n$. Then for each $1\leq i,j\leq k$ such that $i+j=k+1$ you can decompose $a$ as multiplication of $2$ cycles of order $i,j$.